# Parse Json response in C# using Newtonsoft.Json nuget

Tags: json, parsing, json.net

I have the below json response. How to read the CustomerList data from the json response. I will bind this data to a gridview. Using the Newtonsoft.Json nuget.

```
{
  "Status": "OK",
  "StatusCode": "200",
  "payload":{
  "SentItemCount": "65",
  "MatchingItemCount": "64",
  "CustomerList": [
   {
     "EntityName": "Franklin LLC",
     "EntityID": "06012",
     "ContactNum": "913-022-8187"
  },
  {
    "EntityName": "Stanley Firm LLC",
    "EntityID": "02398",
    "ContactNum": "832-980-2056"
  },
  {
    "EntityName": "Zneith Systems LLC",
    "EntityID": "05801",
    "ContactNum": "482-120-9406"
  }
  ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what kind of gridview you are using but you can get data from json by 2 ways

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonParsed=JObject.Parse(json);

DataTable dataTable=jsonParsed["payload"]["CustomerList"].ToObject<DataTable>();

// or 

List<Customer> customerList=jsonParsed["payload"]["CustomerList"].ToObject<List<Customer>>();
```

Now you can use or dataTable or customer list as a source to your gridview

if you decided to use  a list , you will need to create this class

```
public class Customer
{
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public string EntityID { get; set; }
    public string ContactNum { get; set; }
}
```